# ToggleClass with css transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, effect

I got this simple js to toggle a class if the scroll position of that div is greater than 200. The colorize class has a transition: 1s; propertie but the effect runs only when the class is applied and not at the remove state. I understand that when js remove the class, there isnt a transition anymore, so how can I refactor it so works as I wanted?

```
$(".one").scroll(function() {
  let position = $(".one").scrollTop();
  if (position > 200) {
    $(".two").toggleClass("colorize", true);
  } else {
    $(".two").toggleClass("colorize", false);
  }
});

.colorize {
   background-color: red;
   transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: add also the transition to `.two`

Comment: @TemaniAfif It worked! However I bet there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: the more elegant way is to remove the transition from `colorize` and keep it only on `two` ;)

Comment: @SHAMAN The "elegant" way? Uh yes, set instructions that should be in effect all the time inside of selectors that apply all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the transition in the `.colorize` class. When you remove that class from the element, of course the element will no longer have those instructions applied to it.

In order to keep the transition on the element all the time, you must apply it within a selector that applies all the time.

Simply create this:

```
.two {
   transition: 1s;
}
```

And, change your `colorize` class to this:

```
.colorize {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Right! - thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @SHAMAN Don't forget to mark as "the" answer.